# ACF / WordPress: the_field() only displays one field on website

Tags: wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I've used the plugin ACF (advanced custom fields) before for WordPress and it worked like a charm, which is why I am totally confused right now.

Basically, I have a custom URL field called `external_link` in the posts editor of WP.
In the code, I've used the_field to display it and it shows up on my page. However, any other field I've created on ACF and used the very same code - the content of the field won't show up.

```
<h2><?php the_field('external_link'); ?></h2>
```

So for example, I've added a test field called `abouttwo` and used the same rules, the same "the_field" and the URL will not show up on the page. Meanwhile, if I copy & paste the code for 'external_link' then the URL shows duplicated, tripled.

Does anyone know what issue this is?

I've added screenshots from my code-editor + ACF.

I'm developing the page offline via Local, so I can't show an online version.
I'm aware that this is a plugin - I've also reached out to ACF support - but no answer so far.

[image: WP Post Editor]

[image: Displayed on page]

[image: in code-editor]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common accessibility issues with fields arises from redefining the global variable 'post' while invoking WP_Query. If the function wp_reset_postdata() wasn't used after the WP_Query, the_field() might refer to a completely different post where the desired field is empty. Thus, I suggest testing this hypothesis and ensuring that the appropriate function is called after each custom WP_Query. Additionally, you can specify the post ID as the second parameter, which can also assist in resolving the issue. Here's an example:

```
<?php the_field('abouttwo', 123); ?>
```

Where 123 is ID of the post. OR:

```
<?php the_field('abouttwo', get_the_ID()); ?>
```

Moreover, you can verify whether get_the_ID() returns the correct ID by employing this code:

```
<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Oleh Kosarenko, I'll give this a try and get back. I'm just confused - this was working on other websites with no problems at all. Btw, does it make a difference whether this was on a POST or a PAGE?

Comment: You're welcome! As I mentioned earlier, the issue might arise if in a particular template, regardless of the post type, you omitted calling the function wp_reset_postdata() after using WP_Query. This could lead to difficulties when trying to retrieve the desired field.

Comment: so `<?php the_field('abouttwo', 123); ?>` works, the ID of the page I want it to display is 16, however, so `<?php the_field('abouttwo', 16); ?>` displays the correct field. However, when trying `<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>` the ID that is shown to me is 53.  `<?php the_field('abouttwo', get_the_ID()); ?>` doesn't display anything, no field and no ID. How can I fetch the ID of a post/page in that formula? For example `<?php the_field('abouttwo', **echo** get_the_ID()); ?>` causes an error. Thanks for your help. I am so green in all of this :D

Comment: You should utilize the function [wp_reset_postdata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) after each WP_Query. This is the correct approach to resolve this issue. Following the iteration through an independent query, this function reverts the $post global to the present post within the primary query.

Comment: An alternative approach is to employ the function `wp_reset_postdata()` just before invoking the fields using `the_field()`. However, this method is somewhat less advisable. Additionally, using this method does not ensure the absence of other errors linked to the usage of `global $post`.

Comment: you are a lifesaver. Thank you so much. It worked. I indeed had a WP_Query higher up in the php file to display custom posts. I'll read more about the documentation of it.